# how to fetch entries from mongodb and send it to an html page

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb

i used node.js to fetch entries from my mongodb.
right now the entries get postet to an blank html page as a string.
this is my javascript:

```
var app = require('express')();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var dbURI = 'mongodb://localhost/test';

mongoose.connect(dbURI);
var Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
givenid: String,
name: String,
age: Number
});

var user = mongoose.model('lauts', Schema);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
user.find({
    givenid: '000000001'
}, function (err, docs) {
    res.send('index', { docs: docs })
});

});

app.listen(3001);
```

i now want to create an html page with one textbox and a button where i can enter the "givenid".
and then the i want the string elements to appear in single textboxes or outputs.
how can i proceed?
thanks!

p.s. the string looks like this:

```
{
```

"_id" : ObjectId("56137bdb0f2d3b400ef83d25"),
    "givenid": 000000001,
    "email" : "maxima@online.com",
    "name" : "Maxima",
    "age" : 24,
    "__v" : 0
    }

Answer (score 0):

You have to use any template engine like jade to order to render html or you can develop your application using angular where you can call your route from angular and bind your data through angular to html..

you can find lot of step by step guide on both jade or angular..